# How to iterate over multiple vectors and matrices and return a single value?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to create a function that iterates over the rows

```
def function:
    n, d = xs.shape    
    w = np.zeros(d)
    b = 0.0

    while True:
        m = 0
        for i in xs:
            for j in ys:
                if j * (w.T @ i + b) <= 0:
                    w += function2(i,j,w)
                    b += j
                    m += 1
              
    if m == 0:
        break

return (w,b)

N = 100;
d = 10;
xs = np.random.rand(N,d)
w = np.random.rand(1,d)
ys = np.sign(w.dot(xs.T))[0]
b = 0
w, b = perceptron(xs,ys)
```

But I get the following error:

```
     22         for i in xs:
     23             for j in ys:
---> 24                 if j * (w.T @ i + b) <= 0:
     25                     w += function(i,j,w)
     26                     b += ys

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I belive this is because the line if j * (w.T @ i + b) <= 0: is returing a vector instead of a single value. However when I try this line of code outside my function it returns a single value:

```
test = ys[0] * (w2.T @ xs[0] + b)           
print(test)
```

Which returns 0.0. Why would it return a single value here, but a vector in my function?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
   for i in xs:
        for j in ys:
            print(i)
            print(j)
            print( j * (w.T @ i + b))
```

That's what I'd have to do to test and answer your question.  I suppose I could try to "run" that in my head instead, but I'm feeling lazy :)